# Visual Studio 2008 Solution Lost My Folder Structure after crash?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, directory

Visual Studio 2008 crashed, and after that, the folder structure of my solution explorer was lost, so under the name of the solution are mixedd both the *.cpp, *.h files as well as other files. Can I restore to my previous state ?

I have kept a recent backup but changes does exists with newer version, but before restoring my backup, I would prefer a solution of copying just a VS file that keeps tracking of that folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

It seems that the "*.vcproj.*.Administrator.user" file was corrupted ! I just replaced this one with the one in my backup and folder structures are restored successfully.

After searching a little more the situation i found that the VS after the crash changed the XML tag "ShowAllFiles" to  "true" in the file above.

Regards,